# What is the energy loss in the first process?

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

Suppose we have two objects with different temperatures. If we make them contact each other, they will reach the same temperature.

However, if we set up a Carnot engine between them, they will also reach the same temperature, but this time the work is done by the engine. What is the energy loss in the first situation?

Comment: They will reach the same temperature, but they will not transfer the same amounts of heat with the Carnot engine, and it will not be the same final temperature as when the two bodies are brought into direct contact.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks I understand it now. This is an example I found while reading about irreversible processes involving usable energy—> unusable energy.